# How to get the elements class name from a dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I started creating some minor code within my site, and i wanted to do some dynamic creation, so some span tags are created using a javaScript for loop.
In the same code, but a different loop i want to add an Event Listener to the tags.The error i get is the element created is non existent, and i have a few ideas why it's not working, but searching the Web and Stack Overflow gave me no answers.

I've considered putting both for loops into a function and calling that function in a similar fashion jquery works with it's document ready function. But i don't think that will fix the issue

```
var country = ["is_AmericaN", "is_Europe", 
"is_Africa","is_AmericaS","is_Asia","is_Australia"];

var spanInto = document.getElementById("spanSelect");

for(i=0; i<6; i++)
{
var spanMake = document.createElement("SPAN");

spanInto.appendChild(spanMake);

spanMake.className += "spanLanguage" + " " + country[i];
}
```

The code above creates the elements, the code below tries to call them

```
var countryClass = doucment.getElementsByClassName("spanLanguage");
for(i=0; i< document.countryClass.length; i++)
{
countryClass[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

var hrDisplay = document.getElementById("selectiveDisplay");

hrDisplay.removeAttribute("id");

hrDisplay.className = "noDisplay";

},false);
}
```

I expect the working code to, once clicked on any span tag, set the display of the hr tag to block or flex. I dont want to create 5-6 span tags manually, it has to be a dynamic creation.

Comment: What is the exact error you see in your browser's console? Also, please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the position of the adding class

```
var spanMake = document.createElement("SPAN");

spanInto.appendChild(spanMake);

spanMake.className += "spanLanguage" + " " + country[i];
```

Here you are assigning the class after appending it into span, that is wrong you need to assign class before.

```
var countryClass = doucment.getElementsByClassName("spanLanguage");
for(i=0; i< document.countryClass.length; i++)
{
```

`doucment` is `document` and `document.countryClass` should be `countryClass` as you already have the instance of the element

```js
var country = ["is_AmericaN", "is_Europe",
  "is_Africa", "is_AmericaS", "is_Asia", "is_Australia"
];

var spanInto = document.getElementById("spanSelect");

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var spanMake = document.createElement("SPAN");
  spanMake.textContent = country[i];
  spanMake.className += "spanLanguage" + " " + country[i];
  spanInto.appendChild(spanMake);


}

var countryClass = document.getElementsByClassName("spanLanguage");
for (i = 0; i < countryClass.length; i++) {
  countryClass[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var hrDisplay = this;

    hrDisplay.removeAttribute("id");

    hrDisplay.className = "noDisplay";

  }, false);
}
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="spanSelect"></span>
<br/>
//click on any of them to replace the class
```

Comment: Thanks, the excess document and a trivial "doucment" instead of "document" were the problem, now it works as intended. You were of great help, as was Charu who pointed the spelling mistake.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple points to be corrected:

- There was a type "doucment" in your code.Use "document" instead.
- Created elements didn't have any text on it, how will you call click 
  on element when it is not visible in DOM.
- Events are attached to    anchors/button not span.
- Not sure what you are trying to do by    attaching events.

below is the code snippet which works for you when you try to add events on dynamic created elements.Let me know if you need further help

```js
function temp() {
  var country = ["is_AmericaN", "is_Europe",
    "is_Africa", "is_AmericaS", "is_Asia", "is_Australia"
  ];

  var spanInto = document.getElementById("spanSelect");

  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var spanMake = document.createElement("a");
    spanMake.innerHTML = country[i];
    spanInto.appendChild(spanMake);

    spanMake.className += "spanLanguage" + " " + country[i];
  }
}

function attachEvent() {
  var countryClass = document.getElementsByClassName("spanLanguage");
  for (i = 0; i < countryClass.length; i++) {
    countryClass[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("I am called" + event.target);
      //var hrDisplay = document.getElementById("selectiveDisplay");

      //hrDisplay.removeAttribute("id");

      //hrDisplay.className = "noDisplay";

    }, false);
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="spanSelect"></div>
  <div id="selectiveDisplay"> </div>
  <button onclick="temp()"> Call Me </button>
  <button onclick="attachEvent()"> Attach Event </button>
</body>
```

Comment: DOM events are received by [`EventTarget`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) so you can add an event handler to any `HTMLElement` (including `span` and `img` and whatever).